# display json information in panels using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want display all the information from json to some panels. In my json i have two kind of employees (technicians and engineers).

Each employee have some values stored in value_1 and value_2 which i want to display them by those values. 
In each value (value_1 and value_2) i have some information (the year and the path to the filename).

In each panel header i want the name (ex: Tech 1) and in the body all the buttons with the year and the filename as a link.

The idea is to display them separate by value_1 and value_2. (for example all technicians person by value_1 then by value_2)

For example: All the technicians by value_1

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="tech in technicians">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">{{tech}}</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="{{tech.value1.file}}" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="year in tech.value1.year">{{year}}</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

But is not working

The json file look like this

```
{
    "technicians": [
    {
        "Tech 1": [
        {
            "value_1": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        },
        {
            "value_2": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "Tech 2": [
        {
            "value_1": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        },
        {
            "value_2": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        }]
  }],
  "inginiersl": [
   {
      "Inginier 1": [
        {
            "value_1": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        },
        {
            "value_2": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        }]
   },
   {
      "Inginier 2": [
        {
            "value_1": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        },
        {
            "value_2": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        }]
  }]
}
```

I created a controller where i get the json file:

```
 app.controller("my_Ctrl", function($scope, $http){  
    $http.get('json/employees.json')
        .then(function(res){
             $scope.technicians = res.data["technicians"];
             $scope.inginiers = res.data["inginiers"];

        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <div ng-controller="listController">
    <div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="(key, prop) in technicians">
      <div class="panel-heading" ng-repeat="(key2, prop2) in prop">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{key2}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="(key3, prop3) in prop">
        <div ng-repeat="vale in prop3">
          <a href="{{year.year.file}}" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="year in vale.value_1">{{year.year}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xLHJqwGpBYBB81onpQBO?p=preview)**

Answer (score -1):

Please put array name properly for example "Tech 1" to "Tech1" non-spacing and you can access your json like below :

**Json**

```
{
   "technicians": [
   {
       "Tech1": [
       {
           "value_1": [
           {
               "year": 2014,
               "file": "path_to_the_file"
           },
           {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
           }]
       },
       {
           "value_2": [
           {
               "year": 2014,
               "file": "path_to_the_file"
           },
           {
               "year": 2015,
               "file": "path_to_the_file"
           }]
      }]
    },
    {
        "Tech2": [
        {
            "value_1": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        },
        {
            "value_2": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            },
            {
                "year": 2015,
                "file": "path_to_the_file"
            }]
        }]
  }]
}
```

**In Html**

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="tech in technicians">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title" ng-model="tech.Tech1">{{tech}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div ng-repeat="x in tech.Tech1">
        <a href="{{x.file}}" class="btn btn-default">{{year}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```